# JavaScript Array: get "range" of items

Tags: javascript, ruby, arrays, range

Is there an equivalent for ruby's `array[n..m]` in JavaScript?

For example:

```
>> a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
>> a[0..2]
=> ['a','b','c']
```

Comment: yes, coffeescript! [New-and-improved range, slice, splice and loop syntax](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/835).

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Use the [`array.slice(begin [, end])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function.

```js
var a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'];
var sliced = a.slice(0, 3); //will contain ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

**The last index is non-inclusive;** to mimic ruby's behavior you have to increment the `end` value. So I guess `slice` behaves more like `a[m...n]` in ruby.

Comment: >The last index is non-inclusive< Put that sentence in bold (:

Answer (score 25):

The second argument in `slice` is optional, too:

```
var fruits = ['apple','banana','peach','plum','pear'];
var slice1 = fruits.slice(1, 3);  //banana, peach
var slice2 = fruits.slice(3);  //plum, pear
```

You can also pass a negative number, which selects from the end of the array:

```
var slice3 = fruits.slice(-3);  //peach, plum, pear
```

Here's the W3 Schools reference [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp).

Comment: How about linking to Mozilla's javascript reference, which is far more informative and much better written than the W3 schools site (which has nothing to do with the W3C)? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 10):

`a.slice(0, 3)` Would be the equivalent of your function in your example.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: actually it would be `a.slice(0, 3)`. slice in JavaScript doesn't included the end index.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby and Javascript both have a [slice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), but watch out that the second argument to slice in Ruby is the length, but in JavaScript it is the index of the last element:

```
var shortArray = array.slice(start, end);
```