# return all words from given number in list

Tags: javascript

lets say i have a variable in javascript

```
let array = ["John", "Deere", "Elon", "Bill", "Steve", "Michael", "Jordan"];

function getArrayHead(array, index){
    return 
}
```

I want to return all names beginning from Steve. so Steve, Michael and Jordan must be returned how do i write that function? could someone help me please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580239/javascript-array-get-range-of-items

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try writing some code here to solve this yourself. Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: What about using `array.filter`?

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```js
const array = ["John", "Deere", "Elon", "Bill", "Steve", "Michael", "Jordan"];

function getArrayHead(array, index){
    return array.slice(index);
}

console.log(getArrayHead(array, array.indexOf("Steve")));
```

`slice(index)` gives a subset of the original array, beginning from `index`.

`indexOf` returns the index of the element.

Answer (score -1):

That's quite simple! Try this:

```js
let array = ["John", "Deere", "Elon", "Bill", "Steve", "Michael", "Jordan"];

function getElementsFrom(string) {
  return (array.indexOf(string) != -1) ? array.splice(array.indexOf(string)) : console.error("Name not found.")
}

console.log(getElementsFrom("Steve")) //Returns result
console.log(getElementsFrom("NotAName")) //Returns error
```

What this essentially does is that it takes a string input and gets the index using `indexOf`. If the element does not exist, then it returns an error in the console and `undefined` from the function. If it exists, then it simply returns the output using `splice`, which just gets all the elements from a given index when it has only one parameter.

Note that if `splice` has more than 1 parameter, then it interprets the second as the end point and splices that way, with the end point not included.